# How to reload WMTS Tiles after progromattically changing the map center and zoom?

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm implementing a feature for users to select a list item that corresponds to a point on the map.  I am currently able to set the correct map center and the zoom level but the map tiles are blank until I cause a MouseWheelZoom interaction to occur on the map.  How do I get my WMTS layers to update to the new zoom level and map extent?

Comment: Do you want an answer for OpenLayers 2 (tag `openlayers`) or OpenLayers 3 (tag `openlayers-3`)? Please remove one of the two tags, depending on what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it must be automatically updated when changing the view. Maybe is a bug in the 3.4.0 vesion or maybe your new position is beyond the layer `maxResolution`.

Comment: @EricSonaron I have tried the map.render and map.renderSync functions after setting `map.getView().setCenter([...])` and `map.getView().setZoom()` functions.  I can confirm that I am not beyond the layer's `maxResolution`.  I have also tried ol-3.3.0 and ol-3.2.1 with the same effect.

Comment: Try change center and zoom level using an animation: See http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/animation.html. I think that will force the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, changing the `tileUrlFunction` of a WMTS source will trigger a refresh, because that clears the tile cache. If you're lucky and your WMTS server makes proper use of Etags, just using the same url function again will work:

```js
wmtsSource.setTileUrlFunction(wmtsSource.getTileUrlFunction());
```

If your WMTS server just sets expire headers, you'll have to append something to the url to force the browser to refetch it. Assuming you use KVP encoding to talk to your WMTS server, you could achieve this by doing something like

```js
var random = Math.random();
var originalTileUrlFunction = wmtsSource.getTileUrlFunction();
wmtsSource.setTileUrlFunction(function() {
  return originalTileUrlFunction.apply(this, arguments) + '&' + random;
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, and unfortunately neither of them worked in my case.