# In OL3, vector data layer not visible after map setCenter or zoom

Tags: zooming, layer

Migrating a map to use OL3. When I call map.getView().setCenter or map.getView().zoom on the map, the map behaves correctly, but my vector data layer is no longer visible. I have to do a MouseWheelZoom interaction on the map and then the data layer shows up. This is similar to the issue found in this unanswered Stackoverflow post ([How to reload WMTS Tiles after progromattically changing the map center and zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308830/how-to-reload-wmts-tiles-after-progromattically-changing-the-map-center-and-zoom)) except my map tiles render properly, it is my vector layer that is not visible.

I am creating the WMS tiles layer and map with this:

```
  div = @get 'element'

  layers = [ new (ol.layer.Tile)(
    title: 'Imagery'
    source: new (ol.source.TileWMS)(
      url: WMS_VMAP_MAP_SERVER_URL
      name: 'VMAP'
      params:
        LAYERS: 'basic'
        FORMAT: 'image/png'
        TRANSPARENT: true)) ]

  map = new (ol.Map)(
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([ new (ol.interaction.Select)(style: selectedIconStyle) ])
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([ new (ol.control.ScaleLine)(units: 'nautical') ])
    layers: layers
    target: div
    view: new (ol.View)(
      projection: 'EPSG:4326'
      center: [
        0
        0
      ]
      zoom: 1
      maxResolution: 0.703125))
```

an individual feature is created using this:

```
        feature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point([lng, lat], 'XY'),
            title: 'some title'
            latitude: lat
            longitude: lng
        })
        vectorSource.addFeature feature
```

the vector layer is add using this:

```
vectorLayer = new (ol.layer.Vector)(
  source: vectorSource  #new (ol.source.Vector)({})
  style: circleIconStyle  #my defined icon style
  id: 'MYDATA'
)
map.addLayer vectorLayer
```

and when the following event fires...

```
  map.on('singleclick', (e) ->
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, ((feature, layer) ->
    ...
    )
  )
```

...as part of the event handler I am doing this:

```
        map.getView().setCenter [
          feature.get('longitude')
          feature.get('latitude')
        ]
        map.getView().setZoom 3
```

The map centers and zooms correctly, but my vector layer data does not show up by default. Is there something else I am not doing or calling in order to refresh the data layers after setCenter or zoom on the view? or is it something else I have incorrect in how I am setting this up?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The issue was the coordinates were being treated as strings for the Geometry and not numbers. The fix is to ensure that where coordinates are being set, that they are explicitly treated as a number to remove ambiguity from the equation. So everywhere I set a lat/lon (or latitude/longitude) in the map code, I used Number(lat) and Number(lon) instead.

Props to Eric Lemoine for his answering of another issue located at http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.openlayers.devel.ol3/4773 as that is where I saw his solution to that marker display problem and thought it might address mine as well. And it did.